# When an image or other asset is redirected, which url is used in the cache?

Tags: image, http, caching, browser, amazon-s3

If I have an image url http://original.com/image.jpg and the original.com host redirects the request to http://redirected.com/someDynamicName.jpg, which URL will be used to determine caching by the browser? Will subsequent calls to http://original.com/image.jpg used the cached image if the redirected.com host set the image to cache? How does the type of redirect (i.e. 301, 302, or 307) Affect this?

The main reason I'm asking is that I use private urls in s3 to access images. The user must authenticate in order to get the appropriate image url which expires within seconds. This means that the URL is changing in order to make it more secure. The file, however, does not change. I would like to be able to cache the image on authenticated browsers to reduce cost. My current plan is to use a common URL for the image based off it's id in the database (they are user generated images) and redirect to the s3 private url. I would like the original url, which is the same on subsequent requests, to cache.